# Как выполнить кусок кода в node js асинхронно?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как выполнить кусок кода в node js асинхронно? То есть, например, я хочу получить результат функции (естественно после того, как она отработает):

```js
let currentUser = '';
...

currentUser = checkUser(res, req);
console.log("currentUser: " + currentUser);

...

function checkUser(res, req) {
    let body = '';

    req.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString('utf8');
    })

    req.on('end', () => {
        let params = JSON.parse(body);

        console.log("params[user]: " + params['user']);
        res.end();
        return params['user'];
    })
}
```

Но я получаю в консоли:

```
currentUser: undefined
params[user]: admin
```

Значит функция не успевает выполниться до консоль лога. Как сделать выполнение этого кода последовательно?

Comment: Асинхронность — важный, но непростой аспект языка. Попробуйте прочитать весь раздел, скорее всего вы сами потом поймёте, как решить задачу: https://learn.javascript.ru/async

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function checkUser(res, req) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let body = '';

        req.on('data', chunk => {
            body += chunk.toString('utf8');
        });
        
        req.on('error', reject);

        req.on('end', () => {
            let params = JSON.parse(body);

            console.log("params[user]: " + params['user']);
            res.end();

            resolve(params);
        })
    });
}

checkUser().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 1):

Тема асинхронного программирования довольно огромна и способов решить какую либо из асинхронных задач очень много. Задача, которую вы пытаетесь решить вами плохо описана и из того что вы пытаетесь сделать сдесь мало понятно.

Решение, которое вы предоставили не будет работать, потому как вы пытаетесь синхронно получить результат из асинхронного подхода.

Что представляет из себя метод `req.on(...)` - это всего лишь регистратор, он объявляет новый обработчик, который будет вызван в случае какого-то события. А функция всего лишь возвращает результат. Нельзя вот так просто вызвать функцию и получить результат "не произошедшего события", потому как результат будет известен только тогда, когда:

1. инициатор спровоцирует событие
2. создастся событие
3. вызовется обработчик события (получение результата)

Без всех этих действий невозможен результат.
Когда вы пытаетесь вызвать функцию:

```js
let currentUser = checkUser(res, req);
```

На самом деле данная функция только зарегистрирует несколько обработчиков, а в качестве результата вернет `undefined` по той причине что в теле данной функции не объявлен оператор `return` и не возвращается результат.

Тот `return` который относится к `req.on('end', ...)` отработает только в том случае, когда сработает событие `onEnd`, но оно не даст никакого результата, потому как обработчик будет только вызван, а результат этого обработчика никуда не передается, потому как задача инкапсулированного механизма только вызвать обработчик.